# Implement range function without using numbers in code

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

You have to create a function `range`, such that it takes two (integer) arguments `a` and `b` (`a < b`) and returns all the numbers in between them. So:

```
range(5, 10) // should output 6, 7, 8, 9
range(-5, 2) // should output -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1
range(5, 0) // can throw an error/empty/null/undefined/whatever (a is not < b)
// bonus points for non integer handling
range(0.5, 4.5) // 1.5, 2.5, 3.5
range(0.5, 4) // range doesn't make sense, error/null/empty
range(5, 5) // etc. should return empty/null/undefined/whatever
```

Your code must **not use any numbers at all**, but you can use arithmetic operators. If your language has a `range` function in-built, you cannot use that as well.

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Even if I was writing this in normal code without constraints, I doubt I would have any reason to use numeric literals.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG. "bonus points for non integer handling" is not specific enough for this site. You should either define absolute measures (e.g. -10 bytes) or remove this part from your question.

Comment: I decided to close this as a duplicate, as the source restriction seems irrelevant (as feersum said). Of course, the other challenge required to implement the step width as well, but that seems like a trivial thing to change. Of course, anyone who disagrees is welcome to cast reopen votes.

Comment: For me it is not a duplicate; yes one can prefer range has its extremes instead of esclude them so 1..4 is 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript <strike>(49)</strike>(45)

As feersum said, I do not know why anyone would have to use numbers here.

```
f=(a,b)=>{for(c=[];a<b;c.push(a++));return c}
```

Old:

```
f=(a,b)=>{c=[];for(;a<b;a++){c.push(a);}return c}
```

I am sure it can be golfed down further=)

Comment: I believe it has to be named `range`